# finding closest sibling in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in HTML:

```js
$(".remove-post").click((event) => {
      $(event.target).fadeOut();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-bar">
  <button class="remove-post"> delete </button>
  <a class="list">
    <p>post title</p>
  </a>

  <button class="remove-post"> delete <button>
  <a class="list"><p>another post title</p></a>
</div>
```

every time that I click on a delete button I want to delete the closest "a" tag with the paragraph inside it as well as the delete button by itself. I was able to delete the button but can't target the closest a tag to that clicked button
I wrote it in jQuery

Comment: What defines as "closest"? In your given markup, the second `.remove-post` element has two `<a>` that are adjacent to it. Which one would you determine as closest?

Comment: stack overflow made me to put those spaces, it put red underline , that's why i had to put those spaces,

Comment: @Phil - Is `<p>` definitely not a valid child of `<a>`? I thought HTML 5 allowed `<a>` to contain block elements? According to MDN, `<a>` allows transparent content (phrasing and flow), so surely it should be valid? I just tested it through the W3C validator, and it seems valid...

Comment: @ObsidianAge showing my age apparently. Now get off my lawn whipper-snapper 

Comment: closest "a" tag to the specific button that is clicked, I was trying to use ```$(event.target).closest().siblings("a")``` but it doesn't work

Comment: I made a snippet of your code - including the syntax error you have in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to remove the *next* `a.list` sibling, use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```js
$(".remove-post").on("click", function() {
  const btn = $(this)
  btn.add(btn.next("a.list")).fadeOut()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-bar">
  <button class="remove-post">delete</button>
  <a class="list"><p>post title</p></a>

  <button class="remove-post">delete</button>
  <a class="list"><p>another post title</p></a>
</div>
```

jQuery's [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) is used here to collect both the `<button>` and `<a>` so you can fade them out together.

Answer (score 1):

If the button will always stay before paragraph you can do:

```js
$(".remove-post").on("click", function () {
    $(this).next(".list").fadeOut()
    $(this).fadeOut()
})
```

I would recommend you to wrap the paragraph and the button together like:

```html
<div class="side-bar">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button class="remove-post">Delete<button>
        <a class="list">Another post title</a>
     </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <button class="remove-post">Delete <button>
      <a class="list">Another post title</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do so, then you can use this:

```js
$(".remove-post").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut()
})
```